# Lambda Expression Always Returns the First Value

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

I have the following code in my console app:

```
UserManager user = new UserManager();
string lastName = "Aşık";
Console.WriteLine(user.GetBySingleUser(x => x.LastName == lastName).FirstName.toString());
Console.ReadLine();
```

But the console always print out the FirstName of the very first entry in the User table, as if it never performs the lambda expression. Actually, its not performing as the console continues to print out the first value's FirstName eventhough I changed lastName variable something which doesn't exist in the Table.

Below is the GetBySingleUser method definition:

```
public UserWM GetBySingleUser(Expression<Func<User, bool>> filter = null)
    {
        return UserMapping.MapToWM(_userOperations.GetBySingleUser());
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `filter` does not appear to be used in `GetBySingleUser`

Comment: ...to expand... how does the call to `_userOperations.GetBySingleUser()` know which user to fetch?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir yes, i include `filter` in `GetBySingleUser` parenthesis and everything works fine now